# Converse of interchanging order for derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

We know that for a twice-differentiable function $f$, $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y).$$

Suppose there are functions $g,h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,y)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}h(x,y)$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Is it necessary that there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=g(x,y)$$ and $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=h(x,y)$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Nice question. This is related to the existence of a potential function. Besides the condition you stated, you also need a domain star-shaped. Do you know anything about vector fields and potential functions?

Comment: This question is also moving towards de Rham cohomology.  And a simply connected domain should work - it doesn't necessarily have to be a star domain.

Comment: @Marc Let's take the domain to be the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ for simplicity. I know a bit about vector fields but not potential functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y) = \int_0^x g(\xi,0) d\xi + \int_0^y h(x,\eta) d\eta$.  Then 
$$ \frac\partial{\partial x} f(x,y) = g(x,0) + \int_0^y \frac\partial{\partial x} h(x,\eta) \, dy \\
= g(x,0) + \int_0^y \frac\partial{\partial y} g(x,\eta) \, dy \\
= g(x,0) + g(x,y) - g(x,0) = g(x,y) .$$
Also
$$ \frac\partial{\partial y} f(x,y) = h(x,y) .$$

Comment: What do we use in order to justify differentiating under the integral?

Comment: Since you told us that the partial derivatives commute (and this isn't always the case for some pathological functions), you should not be looking for this level of rigour.  Let's assume that the functions in question are smooth.

Comment: That's fair enough. But I seem to get $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=h(x,y)+h(x,0)-h(0,0)$. Is there something missing?

Comment: How did you get that?  $\frac\partial{\partial y} \int_0^x g(\xi,0)\,d\xi = 0$.  And $\frac\partial{\partial y}\int_0^y h(x,\eta)\,d\eta = h(x,y)$.

Comment: $\int_0^x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(t,0)dt=\int_0^x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}h(t,0)dt=h(x,0)-h(0,0)$, no?

Comment: $\frac\partial{\partial y} g(\xi,0) = 0$.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Hmm.. what's wrong with my argument equating $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(t,0)$ with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}h(t,0)$?

Comment: It like $\frac d{dx} f(0)$.  Do you interpret it as the derivative of $f(0)$, or the derivative of $f$, and then set $x=0$?

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks Stephen!

Answer (score 1):

This is related to [Poincare lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_lemma#Poincar.C3.A9_lemma), which states if $X$ is a contractible open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, any smooth closed $p$-form $α$ defined on $X$ is exact.

Define a one-form $\omega=gdx+hdy$ on $X$, obviously $\omega$ is closed since
$$d\omega=\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)dx\wedge dy=0$$
Poincare lemma states $\omega$ is exact, or there exists a 0-form (smooth) function $f$ such that
$$df=\omega=gdx+hdy$$
which is equivalent to
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=g,~\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=h$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(x,y) = \frac\partial{\partial x} \tan^{-1}(y/x) = -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ and $h(x,y) = \frac\partial{\partial y} \tan^{-1}(y/x) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$.  This is defined on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$.  Now suppose that there exists a function $f(x,y)$ satisfying the properties you asked for.  (We cannot use $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$ because that is only defined up to a multiple of $\pi$.)

Now consider $\int g(x,y) dx + h(x,y) dy$ along any curve.  This is the work done by the force field generated by the potential $f(x,y)$, that is, it will evaluate to $f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_0,y_0)$ where $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ are the beginning and the end of the curve.

So in particular, if we compute $\oint g(x,y) dx + h(x,y) dy$ around a circle of radius $1$ counterclockwise around the origin, then using polar coordinates you will find that it is $2\pi$.  This contradicts the previous paragraph which says it should be zero.

Hence your conjecture is not true on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$.