# Prove that $\nabla \times \vec F =0 \implies \vec F = \nabla f$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do I prove that if $\nabla \times \vec F = \vec 0 $ then $\vec F = \nabla f$ for some scalar field $f$?

My lecturer only proved the converse, which follows easily from the symmetry of mixed partial derivatives.

Preferably I would like a simple method of proof, not something powerful like Stokes theorem.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578709/converse-of-interchanging-order-for-derivatives/

Comment: The converse is true only if the region in wich the field is defined is simply connected, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields.

Comment: sorry... I swapped the terms :-( . Not the ''converse'' but the statement in OP   is true only if the region in wich the field is defined is simply connected. The converse is always true because all exact 1-forms are closed.

Comment: Assume your vector field satisfies $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F} = 0$ on some open star-shaped region with respect to the origin. i.e. if $x$ belongs to the region, so does the line segment joining $\vec{x}$ and the origin. Define $f(\vec{x})$ as $\int_0^1 \vec{x}\cdot\vec{F}(\vec{x}t) dt$, you can show $\vec{F} = \vec{\nabla} f$ by differentiation under integral sign followed by integration by parts.

Comment: @achillehui, why don't you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @abel answer added. it is a sort of boring answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume your vector field satisfies $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F} = \vec{0}$ on some open
star-shaped region with respect to the origin. i.e. if $x$ belongs to the region, so does the line segment joining $\vec{x}$ and the origin. Define

$$f(\vec{x}) = \int_0^1 \vec{x} \cdot \vec{F}(t\vec{x}) dt$$

For any fixed unit vector $\hat{n}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x}) =
\left.\frac{d}{ds}f(\vec{x} + s\hat{n})\right|_{s=0}
&= \left.\frac{d}{ds}\left[\int_0^1 (\vec{x} + s\hat{n})\cdot \vec{F}(t(\vec{x} + s\hat{n})) dt\right] \right|_{s=0}\\
&= \int_0^1 \left( \hat{n}\cdot \vec{F}(t\vec{x}) + t \sum_{a,b=1}^3 x_a n_b \left.\frac{\partial F_a(\vec{z})}{\partial z_b} \right|_{\vec{z}=t\vec{x}}  \right) dt\\
\bbox[4pt,border:1px solid blue]{
\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F} = \vec{0} \implies
\frac{\partial F_a}{\partial z_b}
= \frac{\partial F_b}{\partial z_a}}\!\!\color{blue}{\rightarrow}
&= \int_0^1 \left( \hat{n}\cdot \vec{F}(t\vec{x}) + t \sum_{a,b=1}^3 x_a n_b \left.\frac{\partial F_b(\vec{z})}{\partial z_a} \right|_{\vec{z}=t\vec{x}}  \right) dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \left( \hat{n}\cdot \vec{F}(t\vec{x}) + t \frac{d}{dt}\left[\hat{n}\cdot \vec{F}(t\vec{x})\right] \right) dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}\left[ t \hat{n}\cdot \vec{F}(t\vec{x})\right] dt\\
&= \hat{n}\cdot \vec{F}(\vec{x})
\end{align}
$$
Since the direction of $\hat{n}$ is arbitrary, this leads to
$\vec{\nabla}f(\vec{x}) = \vec{F}(\vec{x})$ as desired.

Comment: nice. i like the simplicity and directness of the proof. don't you need $\nabla \times  F = 0$ to show that $f$ is well defined. that is it is path independent.

Comment: This is not boring at all. It's a very nice and simple approach that almost anyone can follow!

Comment: @abel $f$ is well defined because there is only one line segment connecting any point to the origin. This construction does not guarantee the uniqueness of $f$ if one choose a different origin.

Comment: what was i thinking? my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this answer is somewhat "sophisticated", and requires some knowledge of algebraic topology.

Let $X$ be a simply connected $C^\infty$-manifold. Then we have for the de Rham cohomology
$H^1_{dR}(X)=H^1(X;\mathbf{R})=\mathrm{Hom}(H_1(X),\mathbf{R})=\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1(X)^{\mathrm{ab}},\mathbf{R})=0$ (using de Rham's theorem, the universal coefficient theorem, and Hurewitz's theorem) since $\pi_1(X)=0$. Thus every closed $1$-form is exact.

Now if you take $X$ to be a simply connected open subset of $\mathbf{R}^3$, and if $(f,g,h)$ is your vector field on $X$, define the $1$-form $\omega=fdx+gdy+hdz\in\Omega^1(X)$. Saying that the curl of $(f,g,h)$ vanishes amounts to $\star d\omega=0$; but $d\omega=\star\star d\omega=0$, so that by the above result there is $\phi\in C^\infty(X)=\Omega^0(X)$ with $\omega=d\phi$. But this amounts to $\nabla\phi=(f,g,h)$.

Comment: While that's a good proof, the OP specifically asks for something "simple, not powerful like Stoke's theorem". Here you use three big theorems...

Comment: fair enough, but he said "preferably". I think the answer might still be useful to some people, even though not for the OP.

Comment: Yes of course, just pointing out that he may not be happy with this proof (which is a good proof and how I would go about it).