# Existence of a differentiable function given a unit gradient field

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry, vector-fields, poissons-equation

I'm trying to prove that "Given a *unit* vector field $V$, it can always be *uniquely determined* a differentiable function $f$ that satisfies $\nabla f = V$."

To provide you more information, the unit vector field $V$ is actually determined from $V=\frac{\nabla \phi}{\| \nabla \phi \|}$, where $\phi$ is a level-set function. That is, I want to prove the *existence* and *uniqueness* of a function $f$ satisfying $\nabla f = \frac{\nabla \phi}{\| \nabla \phi \|}$.

Can any of you give me a proof or at least some advice?
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance. :)

Comment: You  need to verify $\nabla \times V = 0$. You should find answers in  this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149188/59379) useful.