# $\vec \nabla \times \vec F=0 $ $\implies$ $\exists$ a scalar potential $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi=\vec F$. Prove it.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator, curl

If $\vec F$ be defined in a simply connected region, then  $\vec \nabla \times \vec F=0 $ $\implies$ $\exists$ a scalar potential $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi=\vec F$. Prove it by using Helmholtz decomposition.

It is solved here in a different way [Prove that $\nabla \times \vec F =0 \implies \vec F = \nabla f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149188/prove-that-nabla-times-vec-f-0-implies-vec-f-nabla-f)

Using Helmholtz decomposition, we have:

$$F = \nabla \psi+ \nabla \times \vec G.$$

Then
$$curl\, \vec F =curl(grad\,\psi)+\nabla\times(\nabla\times \vec G)$$
i.e,
$$\vec 0=\vec 0+ \nabla\times(\nabla\times \vec G)\implies \nabla\times(\nabla\times \vec G)=\vec 0.$$

Now using, $\nabla\times(\nabla\times G) = \nabla (\nabla\cdot G) - \nabla^2 G$ or else, how to claim that $$F = \nabla \phi?$$

Please explain in details. Thank you.

Comment: When you study the [Helmholtz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Three-dimensional_space) properly you will immediately see that in your case $G$ vanishes: check out the integrals by which Helmholtz constructed his decomposition. Also: there are requirements on the domain being bounded or $F$ vanishing as least as fast as $1/r$ when $r\to\infty\,.$